# Getting value from splitted string using aws stepfunctions' intrinsic functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I created something like this:

```
{
  "Comment": "A description of my awesome state machine",
  "StartAt": "Splitter",
  "States": {
    "Splitter": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true,
      "Parameters": {
        "out.$": "States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit($.url, '//'), 1)"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.test"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get the second element after splitting the string but it fails with the following error:

```
An error occurred while executing the state 'Splitter' (entered at the event id #2).
There was an error while evaluating the intrinsic function: States.ArrayGetItem(States.Array(States.StringSplit($.url, '//')),1). 
Invalid arguments in States.ArrayGetItem
```

Also I tried like this:

```
"States.ArrayGetItem(States.Array(States.StringSplit($.url, '//')),1)"
```

but the error persist.

I guess it could be done with two `Pass` states but it should be possible to do in just one state.

Comment: Is not possible to use the result from one intrinsic function as the parameter of another?

Comment: Seems like a bug that some Intrinsic functions don't access the output of others.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug from StepFunctions - it should be fixed now.
Thanks for bringing it to our attention!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).